# pdfjs generate new file lack text

Tags: pdf.js, pdflib

I used pdfjs to split the pdf files, then add some watermark(the watermark string contains some Chinese). Finally, generate a new pdf file for browsing. Strangely, some of the text appears incomplete.What's happening?
[image: pdf snapshot]

--------libs version as follows:
pdfjs: 2.16.105
pdf-lib: 1.17.1
vue: 2.6.10

Somebody said: "The CMap is compressed by Webpack". I put it in static resource directory, then the problem still exists. What do I need to do to fix it? thx

Comment: pdf files in English have the same problem.

Comment: Solved! Turn off hardware acceleration for chrome. The problem is currently showing up in a dell laptop, and I think it may be the vendor's driver.